# Loop on files and run command

Tags: loops, powershell, csv, active-directory

Using PowerShell, I need to loop on all the files in a folder and for each file run a command.

For example:

In folder `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\scripts`  I have these files: user_1.csv, user_2.csv, ... user_N.csv

For each file I need to run this command:

```
Import-Csv .\user_N.csv | New-ADUser -Enabled $True -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString Pass123 -AsPlainText -force)
```

This command should be inside a loop that iterates all the files in the folder
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all csv files and pipe it to the `Import-CSV` cmdlet:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\scripts' -Filter 'user_*.csv' |
    Import-Csv | 
    New-ADUser -Enabled $True -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString Pass123 -AsPlainText -force)
```