# Command prompt: loop and run command on all files

Tags: for-loop, command-prompt

I am new to using command prompt. I have a large amount of zip files I need to run a program on.

Running the program on one of the files in the command prompt looks like this:

```
Tabulate.exe -i S:\Packages\ZipFolderName_1.zip -o S:\Output\ZipFolderName_1
```

which spits out a csv.

I have found these posts helpful, but cannot seem to implement for my situation:

[Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop)

[Loop on files and run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513369/loop-on-files-and-run-command)

Answer (score 0):

Read entire `for /?` output, pay your attention to `~` modifiers. In the following `cmd` compound command is used `ECHO` to merely *show* `Tabulate.exe` lines to be executed:

```
for %I in ("S:\Packages\*.zip") do @ECHO Tabulate.exe -i %~fI -o S:\Output\%~nI
```

> To use the `FOR` command in a batch program, specify `%%variable`
>   instead of `%variable`.  Variable names are case sensitive, so `%i` is
>   different from `%I`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

for %%I in ("S:\Packages\*.zip") do (
    rem explaining comments:
    rem %~fI expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    rem %~nI expands %I to a file name only  ↓↓↓↓
    ECHO Tabulate.exe -i %%~fI -o S:\Output\%%~nI
rem ↑↑↑↑ remove `ECHO` no sooner than debugged  
)
```